# What is the difference between "Mubtalat-of-Wudu" of Shia and Sunni?

Tags: shia-sunni, wudu

Concerning "Mubtalat of Wudu (Wudhu) or actually the items which invalidate the wudu (ablution), there seems to be some differences between Shia and Sunni Wudu. I'm relatively familiar with Shia view, but I was wondering what the items (invalidates) are which are not the same between Shia and Sunni.

As the Mubtalat of Wudu based on Shia view: ([farsi.khamenei.ir](http://farsi.khamenei.ir/treatise-content?id=235)
and [http://islampedia.ir](http://islampedia.ir/fa/1390/06/%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%88/) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really know about the mubtilat from Shia's view (I opened the links provided, it was in Persian unfortunately), so I will just mention the mubtilat of wudu' **from Sunni's view**:

1. Passing out gases.
2. Egestion
3. Urinating
4. Ejaculation of semen in any case.
5. Wady (a liquid similar to semen that comes out after urination)
6. Madhiy (a liquid formed when sexually excited)
7. Touching a non-mahram woman.
8. Excessive bleeding.
9. Vomiting
10. Touching one's private part (either with or without lust)
11. Eating camel meat.
12. Sleeping in which you're not conscious. (And losing consciousness in general.
13. Losing your mind such as getting drunk.

**From Shia's view:**

1. urine
2. feaces
3. wind of stomach and intestine which exits from the outlet of feces
4. the sleep in which you are unconscious
5. items which spoil the intellect (aql) such as madness and drunkenness
6. Estehaazeh of women
7. the acts which make us doing Qusl, such as Jenaabah

(Source: Tozih-al-Masaael, Al-Mahshi, Imam-Khomeini)

Comment: Uh-huh, @Abdel Rahman, your answer looks brief and fine. And to much extent it made me aware regarding its differences. جزاکم الله خیرا.

Comment: Rahman,
Would you please add the following brief items which is related to the items which makes the Wudu invalidated based on Shia view (in order to make your answer complete). In order to make it deserved of the chosen answer? (as you wish) :
Shia view:

1: urine / 2: feces / 3: wind of stomach and intestine which exits from the outlet of feces 4: the sleep which … 5: items which spoil the intellect (aql) such as madness and drunkenness / 6: Estehaazeh of women 7: the acts which make us doing Qusl, such as Jenaabah  (Souce: Tozih-al-Masaael, Al-Mahshi, Imam-Khomeini)

Comment: Rahman, I provide the above comment as a brief answer based on Shia view. I reckon it would be appropriate if you add it to your nice answer to make your answer more complete in order to presenting the both Sunni and Shia view, which would be closer to what the question need. (although it is good too now). In that case your answer would be chosen as my favorite answer.

Comment: Alright, done. (Sorry for late response)

Answer (score 1):

Invalidation of wudhu is the same for both Sunnis and Shias. There are two things I noticed not mentioned in the link.

1) If you bleed as in if you get a cut for example.

2) If you laugh during salah.

Comment: Laughing during salah spoils your prayer, not your wudu'.

Comment: If you laugh and your laugh can be heard then you have to do wudhu again. You can't just restart your salah.

Comment: No, check this http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=134945 , it's in arabic though. It says that the acts such as laughing loudly, speaking intentionally etc during prayer doesn't spoil wudu', it just spoils your salah.